# Is it safe to use "get" and "set" as property names in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it generally safe to use get and set as the names of properties for an object literal, like this:

```
var myObject={
    get: 'value1',
    set: 'value2'
}
```

Get and set do not appear to be reserved words in javascript, but I'm worried this could cause clashes with some built-in behaviors. In particular get and set seem to have some [pretty unique behavior in the `Object.defineProperties` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

```
Object.defineProperties(someObject,{
    'Property1':{
        get:function(){
            return property1;
        },
        set:function(val){
            property1=val;
        },
        enumerable:true;
    }
});
```

In this built-in behavior, the `get` and `set` aren't treated as normal properties but actually execute their respective functions when `someObject.Property1` is accessed or assigned to.

Because of how they're used in `Object.defineProperties` I've always sort of treated `get` and `set` as special reserved words. So my question is, is that a good rule of thumb or should I just learn to stop worrying and just use `get` and `set` whenever it seems semantically appropriate?

Comment: They aren't reserved so it is up to you. In other words; the answer is opinion based and therefore is off topic

Comment: @charlieftl no, why should it? The answer is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. `get` and `set` are always treated as normal properties. The fact that they are used to define getters and setters in property descriptors is completely irrelevant.

An example of an unsafe property would be `valueOf`, because it actually changes how an object behaves:

```
console.log(+{}); // NaN
console.log(+{ valueOf: () => 5 }); // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `get` and `set` are valid properties in the object you pass to `Object.defineProperties` is proof that it's safe to use `get` and `set` as property names.

The only time `get` and `set` have a special meaning in JavaScript is when you're creating a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) or [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), but the syntax is different, so there isn't a clash with property names.

Answer (score 0):

the setter getter mechanism in javascript [described](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) , I don't see any conflict or reason to consider it unsafe except maybe others do it too, so careful about overwriting by other libraries so beside that it's good to go.